# Adding missing spaces in text

Tags: windows-7, nlp

I am looking for a program that runs on Windows 7 or web browser and can adding missing spaces in a text.

Example: "Thisisatest." -> "This is a test."

Any price or license is fine. It should support texts written in English.

Comment: Is a webapp where you have to paste in a text field and get the output from another text field OK? Or do you need it to be tightly integrated like the spellchecker in your word processing program and web browser?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul webapp is ok

Comment: With user interaction, for confirmation? Or should it  be fully automated (and just make a best guess sometimes)?  (You don't want to mis-space "doeshit" ;-)

Comment: @Mawg Ideally just make a best guess sometimes (otherwise too many confirmations)

Comment: If you're willing to make your own program, this question at SO seems good (haven't tested myself though, so I'm not answering :/): [How to split text without spaces into list of words?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8870261/3541881)